# Azure Resource Graph Query - List policy state by subscription name

Tags: azure, azure-resource-graph

My goal is to create an Azure dashboard widget with a list of subscriptions with their according policy states.

```
+-------------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+------------+
| Subscription name | Total | Compliant | Exempt | Non-compliant | Percentage |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+------------+
| foo-subscription  |   300 |       270 |      0 |            30 | 0.9        |
| bar-subscription  |   100 |        80 |      0 |            20 | 0.8        |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+------------+
```

For that I am using the Azure Resource Graph Query.
I am able to list the policy states related to the subscription-IDs. But not related to the subscription names.

This query

```
policyresources
| extend complianceState=tostring(properties['complianceState']), resourceId=tostring(properties['resourceId'])
| project subscriptionId, complianceState, resourceId
| summarize complianceStates=make_list(complianceState) by subscriptionId, resourceId
| summarize Total = count()
, Compliant = countif((complianceStates notcontains "NonCompliant") and (complianceStates contains "Compliant"))
, Exempt = countif((complianceStates notcontains "NonCompliant") and (complianceStates notcontains "Compliant") and (complianceStates contains "Exempt"))
, NonCompliant = countif (complianceStates contains "NonCompliant")
by subscriptionId
| extend OverallCompliancePerc = round(toreal(Compliant + Exempt) / toreal(Total), 2)
| order by OverallCompliancePerc desc
```

leads to

```
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+------------+
|  Subscription-ID   | Total | Compliant | Exempt | Non-compliant | Percentage |
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+------------+
| b4757628-9b24-447a |   300 |       270 |      0 |            30 | 0.9        |
| 86fa64ae-6c30-4157 |   100 |        80 |      0 |            20 | 0.8        |
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+------------+
```

The kusto language allows to [join tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer). However, the kusto language [allows the join only for Resources and ResourceContainer tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language#resource-graph-tables). Not for Policy resources.

Is it possible to create a table related to the subscription name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great query and I wanted to thank you for sharing it.

If you run the query in the Azure Resource Graph Explorer, the results appear, there is a slider switch on the far above the results header titled "Formatted results", switch to On, that will replace SubscriptionId with the Subscription Name.

There is the union approach but I had difficulty and it was slow. Here is an example:

```
    Resources
    | summarize resourceCount=count() by subscriptionId
    | join (ResourceContainers | where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project SubName=name, subscriptionId) on subscriptionId
    | project-away subscriptionId, subscriptionId1
```

If running from PowerShell, this is the method I use for resolving subscriptionId to SubscriptionName:

```
# Create a Hash Table for lookups of SubscriptionName by subscriptionId
$LkUpSubs = @{}
For ($sub in (Get-AzSubscription)) {
    $LkUpSubs.Add($sub.Id, $sub.Name)
}

// In the Kusto Query, Add and include SubscriptionName in the | project statement
| extend SubscriptionName = ''

# Run Search-AzGraph and assign output to a variable like $results
# Enrich the results
ForEach ($rec in $results) {
    $rec.SubscriptionName = $LkUpSub[$rec.subscriptionId]
}
```

Here is a working example based on your query:

```
$LkUpSubs = @{}
ForEach ($sub in (Get-AzSubscription)) {
    $LkUpSubs.Add($sub.Id, $sub.Name)
}

$Query = "policyresources | where tolower(properties.policyAssignmentName) != 'securitycenterbuiltIn'
| extend complianceState=tostring(properties['complianceState']), resourceId=tostring(properties['resourceId'])
| project subscriptionId, complianceState, resourceId
| summarize complianceStates=make_list(complianceState) by subscriptionId, resourceId
| summarize Total = count()
  , Compliant = countif((complianceStates notcontains 'NonCompliant') and (complianceStates contains 'Compliant'))
  , Exempt = countif((complianceStates notcontains 'NonCompliant') and (complianceStates notcontains 'Compliant') and (complianceStates contains 'Exempt'))
  , NonCompliant = countif (complianceStates contains 'NonCompliant') by subscriptionId
| extend OverallCompliancePerc = round(toreal(Compliant + Exempt) / toreal(Total), 2)
| extend SubscriptionName = ''
| project SubscriptionName, subscriptionId, Total, Compliant, Exempt, NonCompliant, OverallCompliancePerc
| order by OverallCompliancePerc desc
"
$Results = Search-AzGraph -Query $Query -First 5000

ForEach ($rec in $Results) {
    $rec.SubscriptionName = $LkUpSubs[$rec.subscriptionId]
}

$TimeStamp = (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MMdd-HHmm')
$FilePath = ('C:\Temp\ComplianceReports\ResourceCompliance_CountsBySubscription_{0}.csv' -f $TimeStamp)
$Results |
    Sort-Object -Property SubscriptionName | 
    Select-Object -Property SubscriptionName, Total, Compliant, NonCompliant, OverallCompliancePerc |  
    Export-Csv -Path $FilePath -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The simple slider has solved it! When updating the tile the formatting is taken over to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Great query, you saved me a lot of time. I have tweaked a bit your query trying to get just the last compliance results to be as close as possible to the portal dashboard, but faster.

```
policyresources
| extend complianceState=tostring(properties['complianceState']), resourceId=tostring(properties['resourceId']),timestamp=todatetime(tostring(properties['timestamp'])),policyDefinitionName=tostring(properties['policyDefinitionName'])
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| project subscriptionId, complianceState, resourceId, timestamp,policyDefinitionName
| summarize max(timestamp) by subscriptionId, resourceId,complianceState,policyDefinitionName
| summarize complianceStates=make_list(complianceState) by subscriptionId, resourceId
| summarize Total = count()
, Compliant = countif((complianceStates notcontains "NonCompliant") and (complianceStates contains "Compliant"))
, Exempt = countif((complianceStates notcontains "NonCompliant") and (complianceStates notcontains "Compliant") and (complianceStates contains "Exempt"))
, ['Non-Compliant'] = countif (complianceStates contains "NonCompliant")
by subscriptionId
| extend ['Compliance %'] = round(toreal(Compliant + Exempt)*100 / toreal(Total), 2)
| order by ['Compliance %'] desc
```

Comment: Nice tweaks! However, my problem is still not solved, unfortunately.

Comment: If you just need to show the subscription name, just turn on "Formatted results". As you said, there is no way to join the "policyresources" table with any other one, at least in a Resource Graph query.

Comment: Yes, the "Formatted results" slider has solved it.